# How to reorganize tensor

Tags: tensorflow

Without loss of generality, I have the following 3d tensor

shape (2, 3, 3)

```
[[[1 2 3]
  [4 5 6]
  [7 8 9]]
 [[-1 -2 -3]
  [-4 -5 -6]
  [-7 -8 -9]]
```

I need to reorganize the above tensor as follow

```
[[[1 2 3]
  [-1 -2 -3]]
 [[4 5 6]
  [-4 -5 -6]]
 [[7 8 9]
  [-7 -8 -9]]]
```

That is, a tensor of shape (3 x 2 x 3). How should I go about doing this in tensorflow?

Answer (score 1):

`tf.transpose` is exactly what you want.

If you want to transpose a with shape `[3,4,5]` to `[4,5,3]`, you can use `tf.transpose(a, [1, 2, 0])`